# Laravel Three-way Many-to-Many Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have database like this
`accounts`

- id
- name

`contacts`
 - id
 - account_id
`account_communications`
 - id
 - account_id

and contact model :

```
class Contact extends Model
{ 
    public function Account()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Account');
    }
   public function AccountCommunication()
   {
      return $this->hasManyThrough( 'App\AccountCommunication','App\Account');
   }
}
```

Account model

```
 class Account extends Model
 {
     public function AccountCommunication()
      {
          return $this->hasMany('App\AccountCommunication');
      } 
    public function Contact()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contact');
     }
 }
```

AccountCommunication model

```
class AccountCommunication extends Model
 {
      public function Account()
     {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account');
      }
  }
```

On my controller

```
class ContactController extends Controller
  {
     public function index()
     {
        $contacts = Contact::with('Account')->with('AccountCommunication')->paginate(10);
      dd($contacts);
     }
  }
```

Show me this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'accounts.contact_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `account_communications`.*, `accounts`.`contact_id` from `account_communications` inner join `accounts` on `accounts`.`id` = `account_communications`.`account_id` where `accounts`.`contact_id` in (20))

Comment: the relationship seems so wrong. is `account_communications` the intermediate table?

Comment: Yes.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the `HasManyThrough` relationship and mixing it with `hasMany`. If you just look at glance over [laravel HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) example, You would get better idea of what it actually is used for

```
countries
  id - integer
  name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer --> here is the key role for countries posts
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    title - string
```

Since your structure is way different then what it is being used for. The `account_id` exists on both side so what are you waiting for then?

Just map them through `account_id` e.x

```
class Contact extends Model
{ 
    public function Account()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Account');
    }
   public function AccountCommunication()
   {
      return $this->hasMany( 'App\AccountCommunication', 'account_id', 'account_id');
   }
}
```